# AWS Lambda Function URL deployed w/ Serverless Framework cors allowedMethods set to 'POST' but still able to send GET request

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

- The function is hosted on an image from Amazon ECR.
- Function URL is needed since the function takes longer than 30sec to return a response.

I'm able to send GET request using Thunder Client VSCode with a body and get a successful response.

How does this make sense?
Does it have to do with the function handler response?

```
functions:
  <serverless-function-name>:
    image:
      name: <image-name>
    memorySize: 2048
    timeout: 180
    name: <name-alias>
    tags:
      JobName: <name-alias>
    url:
      cors:
        allowedOrigins: ${file(serverless.${self:provider.stage}.yml):cors.url}
        exposedResponseHeaders: '*'
        allowedHeaders: 
          - Content-Type
          - Authorization
        allowedMethods: 
          - POST
```

I'm expecting the GET request on thunder client to return an error.